# How do I relocate Data directory in mySQL to external drive (macintosh)?

Tags: mac, permissions, external-hard-drive, mysql

I have read several accounts of people installing MySQL and having space issues on their internal hard drive so the data file is moved to an external drive.

I have been through what I believe are the steps to do this with mySQL 8.0.21 using the preference pane MySQL / configuration to specify a new location for the data file. I first made a copy of the file `/usr/local/mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64/data` on my external drive. When I try to start mySQL, the light flashes to green briefly, then back to red.  The error is below:

```
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 1 - Operation not permitted)
2020-08-16T06:05:24.079096Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 52332
2020-08-16T06:05:24.161137Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /Volumes/mySQLPartition/data/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2020-08-16T06:05:24.161149Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Volumes/mySQLPartition/data/ is case insensitive
2020-08-16T06:05:24.169722Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting 2020-08-16T06:05:24.169919Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21) MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

I can say that I have tried the external as both case sensitive and case-insensitive, and as HFS+ and APFS volumes.  I get the same error message about case-incentive file system regardless.

I have set the data directory to be the external volume data file `/Volumes/mySQLPartition/data` using the "Configuration" tab of the MySQL preference pane.

Permissions are set with:

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql data/
sudo chmod -R a+wrx data/
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the [log file](https://serverfault.com/q/42531/579763), just after you try to start mysql?

Comment: I cannot find the log file on my mac.  I looked at the link to log file but it is too in the weeds for me to follow.  I am starting mySQL with the preference pane.  There is an error log but it is not written to.

Comment: Without a log it's hard to say what's going wrong. Best is to find out where it is and see what's written to it.

Comment: mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 1 - Operation not permitted)
2020-08-16T06:05:24.079096Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 52332
2020-08-16T06:05:24.161137Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /Volumes/20MileHill4TB/mySQLdata/data/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test

Comment: 2020-08-16T06:05:24.161149Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Volumes/20MileHill4TB/mySQLdata/data/ is case insensitive
2020-08-16T06:05:24.169722Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-08-16T06:05:24.169919Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Comment: Well Perry, if you search for the warning `can't create test file` you'll find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41504580/1256347). Can you try those fixes as well? And perhaps it's a good idea to take [the tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Thank you but this was not helpful.  I am pretty sure that I have a permissioning issue.  I have relocated the data file to an external drive (/Volumes/20MileHill4TB/mySQLdata/data).  MySQL knows to use it from the preferences configuration and the error log is saying it tried and failed to create the file.  I have tried to address permissioning with: sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /Volumes/20MileHill4TB/mySQLdata/data and sudo chmod -R a+wrx/Volumes/20MileHill4TB/mySQLdata/data.  But mySQL seems unable to gain write access to this directory. I am pretty sure that is the issue.

Comment: Perry, stop putting everything in comments. [Rewrite](https://superuser.com/posts/1577989/edit) your question with new information as you go. It allows you to format it better and it's far more readable.

Comment: If you're so sure about the permission issue, can you please re-write your question to show the permissions of the original location ` /usr/local/mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64/data` and the permission of the new location on the external drive?

Comment: And why is the other question I posted not helpful? Did you already edit the mysql configuration file to point to the new data location?

Comment: Check if the MySQL config file is located here: `/usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf`.

Comment: I am not sure where the MySQL config file is on mac.  There is no my.nf file however.  I am revising the question with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.  I list this as an answer because it is far from ideal.  I am bypassing the launchcd and the preference pane mySQL because I could not get around the binlog index issue that kept terminating my startup.

I can start mySQL on the command line with:

sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/Volumes/mySQLPartition/data/data --user=mysql --disable-log-bin &

I disable the log but it works without disabling too.

I created the external data file initially as follows:

cd [to the location you want the data]
sudo mkdir -p data
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql data
sudo chmod 750 data
cd /usr/local/mysql

bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --datadir=/Volumes/mySQLPartition/data/data

This works.  The pref pane shows that mySQL is active (green light on) but it will not control mySQL and even the pref pane "Stop MySQL Server" will not function.

I woudl love to be able to get the pref pane to control mySQL properly.  But at least this is a workaround with mySQL data on an external Mac drive running OS 10.15.6